# insert multiple entries in SQL using start and end values from PHP strings

Tags: php, sql

The following code inserts 4 persons name and their age in SQL.
I would like to change that function into inserting numbers.
For example. if the value of `$start=100` and `$end=200`, it should insert 101 entries starting from 100 and ending at 200.

something like following

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (number, extra1, extra2) 
              VALUES('100', '$extra1', '$extra2'),
        ('101', '$extra1', '$extra2'),
        ('102', '$extra1', '$extra2'),
        ('103', '$extra1', '$extra2') ";
```

last entry will be ('200', '$extra1', '$extra2')

how can I achieve that ?
here is the original code.

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "newdb");
  
if ($link == = false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
  
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (first_name, last_name, age) 
          VALUES('raj', 'sharma', '15'),
    ('kapil', 'verma', '42'),
    ('monty', 'singh', '29'),
    ('arjun', 'patel', '32') ";
    if (mysqli_query($link, $sql))
{
    echo "Records added successfully.";
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. "
        .mysqli_error($link);
}
  
// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
? >
```

Comment: Please please please use [prepared statement and variable binding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of directly injecting data into SQL query like it's 20th century.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop from your start to your end within SQL;

```
$sql = "
DECLARE @start int = 100,
        @end int = 200,
        @counter int = @start;

WHILE @counter < @end
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mytable (number, extra1, extra2) 
         VALUES(@counter, '$extra1', '$extra2');

    SET @counter = @counter +1;
END"
```

Comment: Note '@counter' is just for readability, you could simply use '@start' as a counter, to lower the number of lines.